# Parse Cloud - Manual Entry for Installation (Push Notifications)

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform, titanium, cloud

I'm using the Javascript SDK and Appccelerator Titanium. The Javascript SDK doesn't have a function to save deviceToken's for enabling push. I've tried various methods but the one that should work (does not) is saving via a Cloud Function. What am I doing wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("subscribeToPush", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var Installation = Parse.Object.extend("Installation");
    var membership = new Installation();

    membership.set("deviceType", request.params.os);
    membership.set("deviceToken", request.params.deviceToken);
    membership.set("channels", ["general"]);
    membership.save(null,{
      success:function(membership) { 
        response.success(membership);
      },
      error:function(error) {
        response.error(error);
      }
    }); 
});
```

After running this function Cloud Log shows that it was created, yet, I don't see it in the data browser.

```
I2014-10-22T01:29:30.319Z] v51: Ran cloud function subscribeToPush for user rCzHEXY5hN with:   
Input: {"deviceType":"ios","deviceToken":"xxxXXXxxx","channels":["general"]}
Result: {"deviceToken":"xxxXXXxxx","channels": "general"],"objectId":"KCWtpcwy4i","createdAt":"2014-10-22T01:29:30.383Z","updatedAt":"2014-10-22T01:29:30.383Z","__type":"Object","className":"Installation"}
```